# Digest Authentication in monero-wallet-rpc

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I have an application and I want to connect it to my Monero wallet. I can use curl to access the wallet using --digest but my app can't use curl. I am using jsonrpc in Ruby and I can make the call to the wallet successfully but there is an authentication issue because the wallet uses digest. Is there a way to disable digest in the monero-wallet-rpc? If not is there anyone who knows how to use digest in jsonrpc? I will post the my code if anyone wants to see it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Ruby's standard net library doesn't appear to have digest authentication support. However, there is a [gem](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/net-http-digest_auth/1.1.1/Net/HTTP/DigestAuth) which adds digest support and there are several HTTP client libraries (e.g. [HTTPClient](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httpclient/HTTPClient) and many others) that also add support.

You can of course disable login altogether on the `monero-wallet-rpc` by passing the `--disable-rpc-login` at startup, though I would only recommend disabling login if you are not exposing the RPC externally (so only listening localhost) and the machine it is running on is sufficiently secured.